# Heat Resistance of Melamine Particle Board

Tags: thermal-radiation

I want to make a cheap thermoforming fixture out of melamine particle board so I can form some PETG plastic sheets. The forming temperature ( hence oven temp) for thermoforming PETG is around 300 deg. F. So the melamine particle board will be exposed to this temp for about 3 minutes. Are there any dangers to doing this? Thank you!

Comment: fumes from the resins?

Comment: Should I outgass the particle board first by heating it up and draw any fumes away with some fans ?

Comment: Personally I would consider other materials... You say 3 minutes, what is the repeat time? Are you considering any cooling? Will this melamine board de-laminate, deform or bulge over time?

Comment: There is no repeat time, this is a one-off piece, no production runs. The melamine board will not be subjected to any tensile loads, just compressive load of about 100 psi, nothing to "write home about".